# how to get all check box in a grid ticked on button click in visual foxpro?

Tags: visual-foxpro

How to get checkboxes in the grid to get ticked on button click, I have tried the following code

```
IF thisform.chkdeleteAll.Value=1
thisform.grdTrans.column12.check1.Value=1
ENDIF
```

Comment: Tell us more about both what you're trying to do and what's happening when you run this code.

Answer (score 0):

In the following sample, an SQL Update statement would change values in a  Form.GridControl.RecordSource "Alias":

```
PUBLIC oForm as Form
oForm = CREATEOBJECT('TestForm')
oForm.Show()
RETURN

DEFINE CLASS TestForm as Form
    AutoCenter = .T.
    DataSession = 2

    PROCEDURE Load
        LOCAL i
        CREATE CURSOR temp (cTest C(1), lTest L, nTest I)
        FOR i = 65 TO 74
            INSERT INTO temp VALUES (CHR(i), i%3=0, i)
        ENDFOR
        GO TOP
    ENDPROC

    ADD OBJECT Grid1 as Grid WITH ;
        ColumnCount = 3, RecordSource = 'temp'
    PROCEDURE Grid1.Init
        WITH This.Column2 as Column
            .AddObject('Check1', 'CheckBox')
            .Check1.Caption = ""
            .Check1.Visible = .T.
            .CurrentControl = 'Check1'
            .Sparse = .F.
        ENDWITH
    ENDPROC

    ADD OBJECT cmdReset as Commandbutton WITH ;
        Top = 200, Left = 220, Height = 24, ;
        Caption = "Reset"
    PROCEDURE cmdReset.Click
        UPDATE (Thisform.Grid1.RecordSource) ;
            SET lTest = .F.
    ENDPROC
ENDDEFINE
```